# Override lombok builder and change value type

Tags: java, java-8, lombok, builder

I have the below class with Lombok `@Builder` where I override one builder method to convert the input string list into an enum list (field `barList`):

(I still use the default method for the other field `number`)

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class Foo {
    private List<BarEnum> barList;
    private int number;

    public static class FooBuilder {
        private List<BarEnum> barList;
       
        public FooBuilder barList(List<String> barStringList) {
            this.barList = barStringList.stream()
                                        .map(barString -> BarEnum.valueOf(barString))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

When compiling, I get this error on the line `@Builder(toBuilder = true)` above:

> incompatible types: java.util.List<com.mypackage.BarEnum> cannot be
> converted to java.util.List<java.lang.String>

I couldn't find any answers where I can override the default builder method and change a value type. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we run delombok to get a better idea of what's happening, and then compile the output.

```
java -jar lombok.jar delombok -p Foo.java >Foo2.java
# Rename Foo2.java or make the `class Foo` declaration non-public
javac Foo2.java
```

gets us:

```
Foo2.java:63: error: incompatible types: List<BarEnum> cannot be converted to List<String>
        return new Foo.FooBuilder().barList(this.barList).number(this.number);
                             ^
```

And then the answer is clear: Lombok needs the `barList(List<BarEnum>)` variant of the builder barList method to exist. By writing it yourself, lombok doesn't generate its own version.

Lombok core developer speaking here: We don't, because it is quite difficult to ascertain if there is a signature clash. Thus, we notice a method with the same name as something we want to generate and with the same argument count, and we don't do any further analysis: That's a 'match' and means lombok doesn't generate this method anymore, assuming that you've taken over the responsibility for it. This is a fine, fine example: There cannot be a `barList(List<BarEnum>)` method in addition to your explicit `barList(List<String>)` method because you can't have 2 methods that differ solely in the generics parts of the arguments! (Try it - won't compile).

Thus, your approach here is fundamentally untenable. The fix is fairly easy - make that custom method something like:

```
public FooBuilder barStringList(List<String> barStringList) { .. }
```

i.e. give it another name. Now lombok will also generate `barList(List<BarEnum>)` and all will be well.

If you want the `barlist(List<BarEnum>)` variant to not exist, then don't, but you'll have to handwrite the `toBuilder()` part of it: At that point it is no longer possible for lombok to automatically know how to turn an instance into a pre-filled builder anymore, if you start just effectively removing the very methods that are needed as 'setters' to make that work.

DISCLAIMER: I'm a core lombok dev.

Comment: thank you for the detailed response. If I already supply `barList(List<String>)` and like you said, Lombok then won't generate `barList(List<BarEnum>)` -> then this is good right? I don't need the default method for that field. Sorry if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: No, the `barList(List<BarEnum>)` method is required by the `toBuilder` part. It not being there is the problem, it HAS to be there for toBuilder to work. Either [A] put it back (by naming your `barList` method something else, or [B] write your own toBuilder impl.